# I need help in finding a particular Draco/Hermione fanfiction

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, dramione

I've been searching for a Dramione fanfiction for a very long time and haven't been able to remember the name.

The general outline of the story follows a severely depressed Hermione following the end of the second wizarding war. Before she is due to go back to school to complete her education she uses the cruciatus curse on herself, visibly damaging herself as well as mentally.

On her return to school she is allowed to live in her own accommodation which happens to be above Flourish and Blotts where she works part time as well to cover her rent.

On returning to school there is a new Defense teacher who takes a different approach to teaching the students returning following the war. The class includes Zabini, Ginny and Draco. Upon finding out about Hermione's self torture, the teacher creates a potion for her which the other students bring to her daily at her appartment to make sure she takes it, this is where friendships start to blossom.

This fanfic also includes a dark Harry, but it is the Hermione part of the story that I remember with more detail, if anybody has read this story and knows the name of it I would be so grateful.

Comment: You'd think so but it seems to be a popular subject - https://www.fanfiction.net/community/Fantastic-Dramione-Fiction/1699/

Comment: Do you recall when you read this?

Comment: [List of Dramione fanfics](http://dramioneficindex.tumblr.com/) - are any of these what you're looking for? (After glancing at a few, I'm now off to get some mind bleach.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor we need another disclaimer (like TVTropes) for fanfic sites - some of those are vile!

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for it too for a very long time, and I found it (by accident). 
It's called "[Victim of the Fall](http://hp.adult-fanfiction.org/story.php?no=600096728&chapter=1)" (adult fanfiction site).

I was reading the first few chapters without realising that it was the one i was looking for. It takes a few chapters to get to the Hogwarts part and the new teacher.

### [Chapter 3](http://hp.adult-fanfiction.org/story.php?no=600096728&chapter=3)

> As to the other alternative, I have found that Mr Flourish of Flourish and Blotts bookshop is renting a small flat above his shop in Diagon Alley. I have been in correspondence with him and he seems to be quite taken with the idea of your living there. I assume he remembers you as a child. He has also mentioned that he would be happy for you to work for him on weekends to pay for your room and board.

### [Chapter 7](http://She%20deserved%20her%20pain.%20She%20deserved%20to%20be%20screamed%20at,%20abused,%20and%20hated.%20She%20deserved%20punishment.%20%20%20%20Hermione%20noticed%20through%20the%20haze%20of%20her%20tears,%20that%20she%20was%20holding%20her%20wand.%20She%20lifted%20her%20arm%20and%20drew%20it%20along%20the%20back%20of%20the%20opposite%20hand.%20%E2%80%9CDiffindo.%E2%80%9D%20%20%20%20The%20skin%20split%20along%20the%20line%20she%20had%20drawn.%20Blood%20pooled%20in%20the%20wound%20and%20began%20to%20seep%20out.%20In%20the%20back%20of%20her%20mind,%20she%20vaguely%20registered%20that%20it%20wasn%E2%80%99t%20a%20deep%20enough%20cut%20to%20do%20any%20real%20damage%20before%20dropping%20her%20hand%20back%20onto%20her%20stomach%20indifferently.%20%20%20%20She%20cried,%20briefly,%20from%20the%20pain%20of%20it%20while%20a%20little%20voice%20in%20her%20ear%20said,%20%E2%80%9CNot%20enough.%E2%80%9D%20%20%20%20No,%20it%20wasn%E2%80%99t.%20She%E2%80%99d%20endured%20cuts%20and%20bruises%20before,%20she%20was%20used%20to%20it.%20She%20needed%20to%20feel%20the%20kind%20of%20pain%20Ron%20would%20feel%20if%20she%20told%20him%20what%20she%E2%80%99d%20done.%20That%E2%80%99s%20what%20she%20deserved.%20And%20there%20was%20only%20one%20spell%20she%20knew%20of%20that%20could%20do%20that.%20She%20picked%20up%20her%20wand%20again%20and%20pressed%20its%20tip%20to%20her%20temple.%20%20%20%20%E2%80%9CCrucio.%E2%80%9D%20%20%20%20She%20waited.%20Nothing%20happened.%20This%20seemed%20worse%20than%20the%20alternative.%20%20%20%20She%20tried%20again,%20this%20time%20trying%20to%20push%20all%20of%20her%20anger%20and%20pain%20into%20the%20word.%20%20%20%20%E2%80%9CCrucio!%E2%80%9D)

> She deserved her pain. She deserved to be screamed at, abused, and hated. She deserved punishment.
>
> Hermione noticed through the haze of her tears, that she was holding her wand. She lifted her arm and drew it along the back of the opposite hand. “Diffindo.”
>
> The skin split along the line she had drawn. Blood pooled in the wound and began to seep out. In the back of her mind, she vaguely registered that it wasn’t a deep enough cut to do any real damage before dropping her hand back onto her stomach indifferently.
>
> She cried, briefly, from the pain of it while a little voice in her ear said, “Not enough.”
>
> No, it wasn’t. She’d endured cuts and bruises before, she was used to it. She needed to feel the kind of pain Ron would feel if she told him what she’d done. That’s what she deserved. And there was only one spell she knew of that could do that. She picked up her wand again and pressed its tip to her temple.
>
> “Crucio.”
>
> She waited. Nothing happened. This seemed worse than the alternative.
>
> She tried again, this time trying to push all of her anger and pain into the word.
>
> “Crucio!”

Comment: It looks like you created a second account. You can find instructions on how to merge them at https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts